# Round a floating point number to next coming number

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to round off a decimal number to the next higher number nn c#.
for example:

23.3 should become 24
25.8 should become 26
26.1 should become 27

currently i am using this code but it is not fulfilling my requirements.

```
double pages = Math.Floor((float)anyNumber / 5);
```

Comment: What about `Math.Ceiling`?

Comment: yep i tried Math.Round but it is not rounding off like i want above

Answer (score 4):

`Math.Floor` rounds down, use `Math.Ceiling` to round up:

```
double pages = Math.Ceiling( anyNumber / 5.0 );
```

Answer (score 3):

[Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do what you want...

```
double pages = Math.Ceiling((float)anyNumber / 5);
```

as an aside, you might choose to cast to double instead of float to avoid extra implicit casts from float to double:

```
double pages = Math.Ceiling((double)anyNumber / 5d);
```

Comment: It suffices to have one of the operands as double to force a floating point division, so the cast isn't needed when you have the `5d` there!